# Building GCC inside a chroot from source

Tags: libraries, chroot, gcc, development

In a previous question I asked about creating a chroot that simulates my embedded device environment. It was suggested that I build from source GCC and binutils first inside my chroot. To attempt this I copied the version of libc and gcc binary on my host machine to the chroot. I then wrote a simple hello world program to a file test.c and tried to build in my chroot as follows

```
  phil@phil-desktop:/usr$ sudo chroot /usr/embedded_chroot1/
  bash-4.2# gcc test.c 
  gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I am not too sure what is going on here with this error. I have copied the gcc binary and libc to my chroot so why am I unable to compile? Must I copy all system source and header files into my chroot also?? I think I have a conceptual misunderstanding with the whole process of using a chroot.

Comment: Have a look at [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878676/gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory-when-compil)

Comment: @UlrichDangel So gcc is not actually the compiler?? Thanks for this link. I am slowly beginning to realise why Linux/Unix experts get paid such good salaries.

Comment: It is a little bit more complicated but gcc is basically an wrapper/frontend and will run the appropriate command which in your case is cc1 but could also be cc1plus for c++. Either way you should try to contact your vendor how to create a build chroot/environment for your system

Comment: Ah thanks for this. The vendor offers absolutely no support whatsoever for this. I guess that at least means that I have no option but to run Ubuntu on my device and built it on an equivalent setup on my dev machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gcc build has the ability to bootstrap itself without any existing compiler on the system. You should be able to [download](http://gnu.mirror.iweb.com/gnu/gcc/) and unpack gcc, and build it inside your chroot without having to copy anything from outside. It has been a while since I've done this, but I remember it was reasonably painless.

Look at the [build instructions for gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/), which detail this process. You will want to build a native compiler, and all the steps should be performed inside your chroot, so that gcc will be built to match that system.

Comment: Ah great - that sounds like a lot less pain than what I am trying to do at the moment. I will try this approach instead

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble with it as there is no makefile but I will accept this answer as its clearly a far better way of doing it that my current method.

Comment: Oops, I gave you the wrong instructions link :) Sorry, I'll update the question. Check out this instead: http://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Comment: Thanks for the corrected link. Even the documentation looks painful.