# How to build gcc inside a Debian chroot?

Tags: debian, gcc, chroot

I used `debootstrap` to set up a minimal Debian system (x86):

```
debootstrap wheezy /var/chroot http://ftp.debian.org/debian/
```

Then I entered the chroot and installed some packages:

```
apt-get install build-essential m4 flex bison libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev
```

I'm trying to build gcc 4.1.3 (don't ask why). I configured it as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --program-suffix=-4.1.3 --enable-languages=c,c++
```

It ran for a few minutes, and then it failed with errors like:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from ../.././gcc/tsystem.h:90,
                 from ../.././gcc/crtstuff.c:68:
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:356:25: error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:388:23: error: gnu/stubs.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../.././gcc/tsystem.h:90,
                 from ../.././gcc/crtstuff.c:68:
/usr/include/stdio.h:36:25: error: bits/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../.././gcc/tsystem.h:90,
                 from ../.././gcc/crtstuff.c:68:
```

However, I have no trouble building a small program that uses `stdio.h`. So I can compile stuff, but not gcc, apparently.

What additional installation/configuration has to be done to the chroot in order to make it possible to build gcc?

Comment: This missing files are in `libc6-dev`. But it should already be installed (`build-essential` depends on it). Do you use the same architecture in your chroot as on the host system?

Comment: This looks like a perfect duplicate of [Building GCC inside a chroot from source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43182) but I'm not sure that the answer there will help you. Please let me know if it does and I'll close as a dupe.

Comment: @jofel: Yes, the host system is 32-bit Debian.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to complete the build after setting:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
```

Edit: I realize now the source of the problem. The gcc that comes with the system knows to search in directories such as `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu`. However, the gcc that I build doesn't search in those directories. Consequently the build fails at stage2.

It seems that gcc doesn't have any configuration options that let you set the header and library search paths, so I'm guessing that gcc-4.1 is just too old (before the advent of the Debian multiarch scheme) and newer versions all know already to search in `/usr/include/<target>` and so on.